# bad file descriptor python socket

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server

im trying to make a udp server that only accept data, and not recieving back to client, and i had this problem, and i dont know what causing this bad file descriptor, here is the server code :

```
import threading
import socket
import logging

class Broker():

    def __init__(self):
        logging.info('Initializing Broker')
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.bind(('', 6668))
        self.clients_list = []

    def talkToClient(self, ip):
        #logging.info("Sending 'ok' to %s", ip)

        print ("Buat Thread Baru")

        while True:
            try:
                data = self.sock.recv(1024)
                if data:
                    # Set the response to echo back the recieved data 
                    response = data
                    self.sock.send(response)
                else:
                    raise error('Client disconnected')
            except:
                self.sock.close()
                return False


            self.sock.sendto("ok", ip)


    def listen_clients(self):
        while True:
            msg, client = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
            self.sock.settimeout(20)
            logging.info('Received data from client %s: %s', client, msg)
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.talkToClient, args=(client,))
            t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make sure all log messages show up
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    b = Broker()
    b.listen_clients()
```

Answer (score 1):

UDP is connectionless, so in your thread-code a error `Client disconnected` is never possible. But for any other error (in your case probably `socket.timeout`), the socket is closed. Subsequently, in your main program a `bad filedescriptor` error is raised.

If you want timeout in the thread, you need to open a new socket. And also, you have to send a hello-message to the client, so he knows the new port for the one-to-one communication.

Also notice: UDP is not reliable.